# Can't listen to music with iPhone speaker

Tags: iphone, itunes, audio, music, speakers

I am using an iPhone 4 running ios 7.1.1. Recently, I've had a very frustrating problem, and it is not being able to listen to music with speaker. I'm pretty sure the speaker isn't broken because I can use it for alarms. Also, in my voice memos, the sound works although I have to click that speaker button on the top right corner so that the sound would come out of the speaker instead of the earpiece (top speaker).

When listening to music, there is completely no sound, and I can't adjust the volumes. Here's a screenshot of my music.

[image]

I think the problem first occurred after recording with my voice memos and syncing my phone to iTunes to transfer my recording from my phone to PC. After that, there's just no sound coming out of my phone speaker. The music works when i'm using earphones. It's still frustrating though. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The music slider grays out to indicate that it no longer has control over the volume of an output device. This is most likely because there is a volume control on your speakers that overrides the iPhone's internal volume control.

Have you tried increasing the volume using the control on the speakers?

Comment: I found out that the iPhone is stuck in dock mode. I've temporarily solved it by cleaning the docking port with a toothpick.Though, the problem is still reoccurring. Do you have any idea?